# Android Custom DialogBox method on start or when cancelled

Tags: android, methods, dialog, overriding

I created custom dialog box like in [developer's site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) and I wanna know what method is started when dialog pops up or dismiss. I'm looking for something like onResume not for void method.

Comment: i tried it before to print in these override methods..but no one called from these..onstart(),onResume(),onDestroy(),onstop(),onPause().

Comment: I've got the same situation, that's weird if none of these isnt called.